# Why can't I move .mp3-files, but .txts?

Tags: java, file, mp3, move

So I'm currently trying to move .mp3-files via Java. Afterwards they should be placed in folders for their interpret and album

There I came up with this code:

```
import java.io.File;

public class Storage {
    String location;

    public Storage(String location){
        this.location = location;
    }

    public void createFolderIfNotExisting(String name){
        File folder = new File(location+name);
        if(!folder.exists()){   
            folder.mkdir();
        }
    }

    public void putInto(String file, String interpret, String album){
        createFolderIfNotExisting(interpret);
        createFolderIfNotExisting(interpret + "//" + album);
        File currentFile = new File(location + file);
        File futureFile = new File(location + interpret + "//" + album + "//" + file);
        currentFile.renameTo(futureFile); 
    }
}
```

<strike>(Location has to be ending on `//`)</strike> (edit)
(Location has to be ending on `/`)

It appears to be creating the folders. But it's not moving the mp3-file. If I try the same with an .txt-file the .txt-file is moved, what appears strange to me.

I also checked if the .mp3-File is correctly recognised. Therefore I used `currentFile.exists()` . And it is.

So... I am really lost over here. Help would be kindly appreciated. :)

Comment: Why are you using `//`? The directory delimiter is `/` (at least as far as Java is concerned).

Comment: That's the way I learned it. (Taught in school.) Windows does \ and you have to substitue them with `//`, at least as far as I am concerned. `//` always worked fine for me and all school projects.

Comment: As far as I'm aware you only need to put a double slash for a backslash "\\" Java works with a single forward slash "/" for directories

Comment: Then you've learned bad stuff. Windows native separator is \ which in Java would need to be escaped to \\. The *nix native separator is `/` which doesn't need to be escaped, and Java understands it so that you can use `/` and it will work correctly on all platforms.

Comment: Okay I tested it out and that's the solution. :o Wow I'm feeling really shit-loaded right now. My computer science teacher has to have been a good one... Happily facing my A-Levels :/

Comment: But a really BIG thanks to you. <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Kayman, who helped me figure out that there was a Syntax Error.

The code itself was completely fine. :)